# Error in query:LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method

Tags: c#, linq

I have to get checkboxes selected in edit page.For that i have a query like this:

```
var queryFI=(from u in _db.User where u.UserID==id where u.IsActive==1
                             select u);
            var join_queryFI=from r in queryFI join f in _db.Financial on r.FinancialID equals f.FinancialID
                             into c
                             from d in c.DefaultIfEmpty()
                             select new viewpartial
                             {
                               Text = d.FiName,
                               Value = d.FinancialID.ToString(),
                               Selected = d.FinancialID == r.FinancialIntermediaryID ? true : false                              
                             };

            ViewBag.IfcList = join_queryFI.ToList();
```

I got an error:

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression
```

Pls help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`SqlFunctions.StringConvert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466166.aspx) method instead of `ToString`

Try this once, `SqlFunctions.StringConvert(d.FinancialID)`

Comment: assuming `d.FinancialID` is proabably an int, you'll have to cast to a double or decimal (as `SqlFunctions.StringConvert` has no overload taking an int as parameter) : so `SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)d.FinancialId)`

Answer (score 1):

You could convert to string after executing the query:

```
var queryFI = (from u in _db.User
                where u.UserID == id
                where u.IsActive == 1
                select u);
var join_queryFI = from r in queryFI
                    join f in _db.Financial on r.FinancialID equals f.FinancialID
                        into c
                    from d in c.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    select new viewpartial
                    {
                        Text = d.FiName,
                        Value = d.FinancialID,
                        Selected = d.FinancialID == r.FinancialIntermediaryID ? true : false
                    };

ViewBag.IfcList = join_queryFI.ToList().Select(x => new { Text = x.Text, Value = x.Value.ToString(), Selected = x.Selected }).ToList();
```